# Ronin wallets being compromised

Tags: tokens, erc-20, smart-contract-wallets, address.transfer, wallet-transfer

[image]I want to format or configure my ronin wallet in a way that if any ETH comes into the address, it will automatically be sent to another address.

I have the feeling that my private key is being compromised, and I used the address as payment address for a website and I can't easily change to another address, so I need a way to automate any payment that comes in to that wallet to another address fast.

I've googled to the ends of the earth and haven't seen any tutorial on this. I saw something about using web3js to watch address and forward any incoming eth fast to another address as soon as it enters with a script, but the person didn't say how to do this.

Comment: If the private key has been compromised that account is no longer under your sole control. The safest option will be to create a new one.

Comment: But there's other to create script to make auto transfer of slp,weth and axs because i have unclaimed of slp to my account.

Comment: The other part will also run an auto transfer script.

Comment: How to add what apps can i use?

Comment: I search on google and youtube i didnt know how to create script

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not aware of a sweeper bot for ronin wallets.

Comment: But theres is possible using html and css to make auto function? Like clone the site?

Comment: I think you meant using javascript. You should consider that it is an extension, not a website. It is likely it could be programmed, but I haven't done a browser extension so I couldn't help you there.